# List of Android OS services/system apps with dependencies?

Tags: applications, settings, system-apps, services, developer-options

Is there a list of Android OS services/system apps including dependencies, similar to what can be displayed and configured in Windows using `msconfig.exe`? Researching every single one individually is just cumbersome, there must be a list of some sort for developers somewhere.

[This map](https://www.cnblogs.com/mimamo/p/3936666.html) *kind of* gives an impression, but most apps/services listed in my device are not shown and I'm not sure if the graph edges represent dependencies or just exchange of information.

NOTE: The device in question is not rooted yet.

Comment: I assume you are talking about rooted devices that is an important fact and have to be mentioned in your question please edit it and refine your question.

Comment: On rooted device: `getprop | grep running` shows running native services handled by `init` (like those shown under `msconfig`'s Services tab). `dumpsys -l` and `service list` return Java system services. `dumpsys activity services | grep app= | grep -v app=null` returns Java app services. `ps --ppid $(pgrep zygote)` returns all running app processes (system and user). What's your exact purpose to get all this information?

Comment: In fact, I'm referring to stock devices without root. With new devices, I usually try to turn off all services that are not required for my purposes in order to cut down power consumption. This often disables a desired app or UI/device function and it's usually very time consuming to find out which service is responsible. Luckily, I did not have to deal with many dependencies so far (as is the case with Windows services), but disclosure of the function and purposes of all running services would safe a lot of time